# how to get exact part of Bitmap object

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

i am using the getPixels of Bitmap in C# to detect patterns of colors. I have an image file, but I need only to investigate a part of the file (exactly a rectangle inside of the image, cropped 5% from all sides)
I was wondering where is the origin (0,0) of the file so I can use a simple function that goes through all the pixels (see code). is there a convention of where is the 0,0 ??? top left? top right? bottom left? bottom right?

the function i show you here is ok for me, no need for a more effective way to check the file, because the file is not big enough. so maximum 1 second if i go through all the file. I just need to understand how the axis x and y are located

thank you,
Josh.

```
    ulong CountPixels(Bitmap bm, Color target_color)
    {
        // Loop through the pixels.
        ulong matches = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < bm.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bm.Width; x++)
            {

                if (bm.GetPixel(x, y) == target_color)
                {
                    matches++;
                }
            }
        }
        return matches;
    }
```

Comment: simply start your `x` and `y` from the point you want. like if the point is 100,100 and the square should be 50x50 `for( x = 100; x < 150, x++)`

Comment: Coordinates in an image typically start from the top left corner. X goes to the right, Y goes down. Some image formats (like .bmp) treat this differently internally, but that should not concern you unless you are editing the raw bytes inside image files. Side note: GetPixel is horribly, horribly slow. You may want to look into `LockBits` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get a Rectangle as a parameter and look just at the points inside that rectangle, to make sure that all points in rectangle falls inside the bitmap, you need to do `Math.Min(bmp.Height, region.Y + region.Height)` and `Math.Min(bmp.Width, region.X+Region.Width)` instead of just `region.Y + region.Height` and `region.X+Region.Width`:

```
ulong CountPixels(Bitmap bm, Color target_color, Rectangle region)
    {
        // Loop through the pixels.
        ulong matches = 0;
        for (int y = region.Y; y < Math.Min(bmp.Height, region.Y + region.Height); y++)
        {
            for (int x = region.X; x < Math.Min(bmp.Width, region.X+Region.Width); x++)
            {

                if (bm.GetPixel(x, y) == target_color)
                {
                    matches++;
                }
            }
        }
        return matches;
    }
```